Candlestick Plot Error in Google Colaboratory
I'm trying to run this code - https://colab.research.google.com/github/Worlddatascience/DataScienceCohort/blob/master/6_How_to_Create_a_Candlestick_Chart_using_Python.ipynb in Google Colab but keep facing this error
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower' when attempting to run line 11 of the code which initialises the Candlestick object which is a cufflinks quantFig.
Does anyone know why this code no longer works? Code is attached below:
!pip install backtrader #Code to Install Backtrader
pip install yfinance #Code to install yfinance
from datetime import datetime #Code to display time
import pandas as pd #Used for high level Data Indexing processes
import yfinance as yf #Code to import Yahoo Finance API
DISNEYSTOCK = yf.download('DIS',start='2019-09-30',end='2020-09-30',progress=False,auto_adjust=True) 
import cufflinks as cf   #A powerful data visualization library used for Financial Data Science processes
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode #Plotly and cufflinks work in conjunction
cf.go_offline() #gives ability to plot offline
init_notebook_mode() #gives ability to plot things proportionately in the notebook
Candlestick= cf.QuantFig(DISNEYSTOCK, title="Disney Stock", legend='top', name='DIS') #Quantfig, used for Quanitiative Analysis and plot Timeseries data
#The legend is where we want our Title displayed
Candlestick.add_volume() #Adding parameters for a Volume chart (measure of shares and trading volume over a specified time)
Candlestick.add_sma(periods=20, column='Close', color='red') #Simple Moving Average for a 20 day period 
#A 20-day moving average would average out the closing prices for the first 20 days as the first data point.
Candlestick.add_ema(periods=20, color='green') #Exponential Moving Average for a 20 day period
#The code underneath is to create a professional Candlestick Chart in Google Colab
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'colab'
Candlestick.iplot()

Thanks so much!

The download defaults to multi-index columns, so change to yf.download('DIS', start='2019-09-30', end='2020-09-30', progress=False, auto_adjust=True, multi_level_index=False)!

That is specifically because the tuple object has no attribute lower....
